# Jquery append method and colouring of a single word

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help to append several lines in my webpage using jquery for a tic tac toe game

```
       <aside >
            <h2>History</h2>
          <span id="History" > </span> <span id="Won"></span>       

        </aside>




if(Case1 == "X" && Case2 == "X" && Case3 == "X") {
  $("#History").append("Player 1  ")
  $("#Won").append("won ").css("color","rgb(240,30,30)")


else if(Case1 == "O" && Case2 == "O" && Case3 == "O") {
  $("#History").append(" Player 2 ")
  $("#Won").append(" Won ").css("color","rgb(240,30,30)")
```

I need it to display like that after a player win and the "Won" must be in red:
  Player 1 won
  player 2 won

the issue that i have is i cant make it line by line .. its becomes like this player 1 player 2 won won i tried using  but it not good

Comment: Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to edit your question to meet the criteria.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/m0obd7 i want it to look like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be appending new elements not just words into the divs as well as line breaks with the br tag and make your container elements divs instead of spans as spans are inline, use float-left and float-right on the divs to keep them aligned horizontally, also it is good practice to start using CSS files to style your elements instead of doing inline styling, so make some CSS classes for your divs and the spans which you will be appending to the divs to set the color, to be honest I don't think you need two divs but if so and the space between is too much you can add margin-right to the right floating div to reduce the space between text in left div and right div:

CSS:

```
.divLeft{
   float: left;
}

.divRight{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 85%;
}

.spanText{
  color: rgb(240, 30, 30);
}
```

HTML:

```
<aside >
        <h2>History</h2>
      <div class="divLeft" id="History" > </div> <div class="divRight" id="Won"></div>       

    </aside>
```

JQUERY:

```
if(Case1 == "X" && Case2 == "X" && Case3 == "X") {

  $("#History").append("<span class='spanText'>Player 1 </span><br/>");
  $("#Won").append("<span class='spanText'>won</span><br/>");
}else if(Case1 == "O" && Case2 == "O" && Case3 == "O") {
   $("#History").append("<span class='spanText'>Player 2 </span><br/>");
  $("#Won").append("<span class='spanText'>won</span><br/>");  
}
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tu9rdpw3/4/

Comment: i dont want to clear the old values the game goes on and the history is not cleared

Comment: @IrfanSlayer One moment then, fixing the answer.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/m0obd7 
i want it to look the that ^^ if possible ty

Comment: @IrfanSlayer I added more to the answer, I hope this gives you what you need.